# Existing Flutter project not show in Android Studio while import

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am importing existing flutter project in Android Studio. while open project it's only show External Library folder but not show project folder.  I am trying to open https://github.com/geweald/flutter_onfido.

Here I am attaching video link of issue:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VmeH1AhtTP5-YpQ3WRwsBLXZxUa2ox8F/view?usp=sharing

Android Studio detail:
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3

Note: This issue happen with existing download from GitHub.

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87BVG.png)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue with android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3.
After change android studio to 4.2.2, every thing works fine.

Answer (score 0):

be sure you selected **Project** option in the options situated on left top corner of the ide

Answer (score 0):

Select Project option in the options situated on left top corner